# Blazor async cascading value always null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blazor, cascading

Let's say I have the following code in `MainLayout.razor`

```
<CascadingValue Value="@(async () => await someclass.GetValueAsnyc())" Name="asyncValue">
  <article class="content px-4">
   @Body
  </article>
</CascadingValue>
```

And in Index.razor:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
@code{
     [CascadingParameter(Name = "asyncValue")] public string AsyncValue{ get; set; }


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   //do something with AsyncValue- it is always null
}
}
```

My assumption is that the declaration of the variable in `Index.razor` isn't awaiting the cascading value in `Mainlayout.razor`. It does work is I call the method synchronsly with `.Result` at the end, but that's not what I would like to do if possible.

Does anyone have any guidance or can point me in the right direction so that the cascading value loads asynchronously?

Comment: If you do async, I'm afraif that the actual type of the property can end up as `Task<string>` and not `string`. Maybe try to match that type and see? On the other hand, you can "calculate" the value in @code block in MainLayout, and then just pass a property that contains the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should help.

First a consumer component.  The cascaded value is a `Task` which may or may not have completed.  To consume it you `await` it.  If it's already completed the there's no awaiting to do.  It provides the result immediately.

```cs
<h3>@this.value</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.OnClick>Get Value Again</button>
@code {
    private string value = string.Empty;
    [CascadingParameter] private Task<string>? DataTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (this.DataTask is not null)
            this.value = await DataTask;
    }

    private async Task OnClick()
    {
        if (this.DataTask is not null)
            this.value = await DataTask;
    }
}
```

And a test page. I haven't put it in a layout or App as it's easier to see what's happening in a test page.  The cascaded value is a `Task<string>` field that you assign a method to.

```cs
@page "/Test"

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>

<CascadingValue Value="this.DataTask">
    <MyComponent />
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private Task<string>? DataTask;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DataTask = GetSomeDateAsync();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetSomeDateAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
}
```

This is basically how the AuthenticationState cascade works.

Comment: Very interesting! I really appreciate you sharing this, I will give it a try later and report back!

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, this seems to have done it, thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem (CascadingValue is set when first go to page, but null on a reload). I have it in MainLayout.razor as <CascadingValue Value=PopupMessageBox> and in MainLayout.Razor.cs as "public PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; private set; }" Are you saying that in the inner razor file instead of declaring it as "private PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; set; }" I should declare it as "private Task<PopupMessageBox> PopupMessageBox { get; set; }" and then await it? This strikes me as weird that I can declare it both ways.

Comment: @DavidThielen - please can ask this as a new question., referring to this answer.  You only declare it as a `Task<PopupMessageBox>` if you cascade a `Task<PopupMessageBox>`.  I'll take a look at it you (unless someone else beats me to it!)

Comment: OK I've just seen you did.